# Scalar multiply of 2 vectors Eigen

Tags: c++, vector, eigen

I've got some serious problem with basic scalar multiplication of 2 vectors in Eigen lib.
When I have two vectors....both are the rows of matrix..so... I must second .transpose();, I must to get one number..so how its possible that I can access to result of this vectors in 1 iterator 2,3,4,5...??????!!!!!

```
    q_c=matVk.row(ks);
     lk=(matVk.row(i).transpose());
```

vectors multiply :

```
      hore= q_c * lk;
```

the result is totally different than have to be.....and the values in vectors are ok,,i checked it,,I try everything to solve this....I try more specific init.: of vectors: same result

```
    VectorXd hore(1);
VectorXd lk(k);
VectorXd q_c(k);
```

Comment: I don't think you have asked your question clearly enough. When you say the result is totally different, what do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: correct :scalar multiply of vectors...i expect one correct result: 0.138 ..no 0.00015 0.100015 0.000000000051 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the `typedefs` defined in the documentation:
    typedef Matrix< double , 1, Dynamic > RowVectorXd
    typedef Matrix< double , Dynamic , 1> VectorXd

If you multiply a column vector to a column vector, you will get the result what you are getting as question details are not much clear. But I guess this is the mistake you are making. Try this instead:

```
VectorXd hore(1);
VectorXd lk(k);
RowVectorXd q_c(k);
hore = q_c*lk
```